# Mix Gradients in WPF

Tags: wpf, gradient

I want to Mix two gradient vertically, in below code i have made two gradient which are left to right both are different and has 5 stop now i want to make a vertical(from up to down) gradient with 2 stops and wants to use these two gradients as stops just like i am using colors now.

Up = Gradient1;
Down = Gradient2;

```
LinearGradientBrush gradient1 = new LinearGradientBrush();
gradient1.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
gradient1.EndPoint = new Point(1, 0);

gradient1.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.AliceBlue, 0));
gradient1.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Beige, 0.2));
gradient1.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.BlanchedAlmond, 0.4));
gradient1.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Chartreuse, 0.6));
gradient1.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Cornsilk, 0.8));

LinearGradientBrush gradient2 = new LinearGradientBrush();
gradient2.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
gradient2.EndPoint = new Point(1, 0);

gradient2.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Aqua, 0));
gradient2.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Cyan, 0.2));
gradient2.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.DarkOrange, 0.4));
gradient2.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.DarkViolet, 0.6));
gradient2.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.GhostWhite, 0.8));

label1.Background = gradient1; 
label2.Background = gradient2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [GradientStop Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.gradientstop.aspx) page on MSDN (and you *should* get used to visiting MSDN), you will see that there is no property named `GradientStop`, no property of type `GradientStop` and no constructor that takes an input parameter of type `GradientStop`. Therefore, you can *not* use a `GradientStop` inside another `GradientStop`.